# definition of variable

Tags: java, multithreading

I have problem with declaration of variable. iam trying  to prepare code using Multi threading
but i have problem with declaration of variable. Now iam  confused, whether is possible to put Scanner into second not main class- i suppose that yes, but i don´t know how declare variable. Exception is - ***Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context***
    at test1.PIN.main ...

```
public class PIN{

    static int a;

class Runner extends Thread{

public void run(){

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    for(int i= 1; i<4; i++){
    System.out.println("PUT your PIN: ");
    int a = sc.nextInt();

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(PIN.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }

 if(a ==1234){
     System.out.println("PIN  OK");
 } else {System.out.println("PIN NOK");}   

}
}
}

public static void main(String[] args){

    Runner r = new Runner();
    r.start();
```

Comment: Your class `Runner` isn't static, yet you use it in the static method `main`.

Comment: Please indent your code to make it readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare `Runner` `static inner class`. Non static inner classes are instance bound so you need outer class instance to create object of non-static inner class. And because your inner class is not static you can not access it inside `main` which is `static-context`

```
static class Runner extends Thread
```